# Bootstrap modal shown and hidden events not firing when injected via MVC partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In ASP.NET MVC 5, I have a bootstrap modal with id `#modal` which gets loaded as part of a *view*, when certain conditions are met (conditions omitted for brevity). I have `#modal`'s `shown.bs.modal` and `hidden.bs.modal` functions implemented in a js file: `main.js`

So far so good, everything works fine. However, in the scenario where the above-mentioned conditions are *not met*, the modal is injected in the view's HTML via an AJAX call, as part of a *partial view*. The modal is exactly the same as the one mentioned before (same `#modal` id, same everything). However, this time the `shown.bs.modal` and `hidden.bs.modal` functions in `main.js` are not firing. Why is that?

Comment: You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your event handlers in `main.js`:

```
$('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) { ... });
$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { ... });
```

To delegated event handlers:

```
$('body').on('shown.bs.modal', '#modal', function (e) { ... });
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '#modal', function (e) { ... });
```

You can replace `body` with whichever parent container you have `#modal` enclosed in. For a detailed explanation refer to the link in [@Stephen Muecke's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314940/bootstrap-modal-shown-and-hidden-events-not-firing-when-injected-via-mvc-partial#comment65962166_39314940).